# Aurelia: performance/efficiency difference: declared view-elements vs inline DOM in repeat.for

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

Is there a performance or efficiency difference between these two options in a repeat.for:

**Option 1: inline element**

```
<div repeat.for="row of data">
  <span>${row.title}</span>
  <span>${row.someData}</span>
</div>
```

**Option 2: custom view element**

```
<view-element repeat.for="row of data" row.bind="row"></view-element>
```

where view-element is:

*view-element.js*

```
import { bindable } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class ViewElement {
  @bindable row;
}
```

*view-element.html*

```
<template>
  <div repeat.for="row of data">
    <span>${row.title}</span>
    <span>${row.someData}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

If the view-element contained a lot of bindings, would it make a difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a custom element is definitely going to be more "heavy weight" than not having one because it brings in a number of other runtime mechanisms behind the scenes which aren't there with just a normal binding.

That doesn't mean it's slow or heavy. It just means, relative to not having one, it's going to be a bit more heavy.